# wordpress date_query with after array return 0 result

Tags: php, wordpress

Please check my query below

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'properties',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'before' => array(
                    'year' => $ed[0],
                    'month' => $ed[1],
                    'day' => $ed[2],
                ),
                'after' => array(
                    'year' => $st[0],
                    'month' => $st[1],
                    'day' => $st[2],
                ),
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'broker_id', 'value' => $broker_ID, 'compare' => '=')),
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
$properties = new WP_Query($args);
$propertydata = $properties->posts;
```

The above query return an empty result but if I remove 'after' array from it, it will return the correct posts.
please note that the dates arrays are correct.

What is the problem, I can't figure it out

Comment: Can you provide an example for the `$st` and `$ed` variable please?

Comment: check this please 
$ed = array( '2017','12','31');
$st = array( '2017','12','01');

Comment: This is just a guess, but can you parse your date values to int? Maybe the `'01'` is causing a problem. The function expects Integer values. `$ed = array_map('intval', $ed); $st = array_map('intval', $st);`

Comment: thank you but It's not working

Comment: According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters, the 'day' value looks like it should be a string WITHOUT leading zeroes. So try '1' instead of '01' for the day parameter.

Comment: I tried it with no luck